Error when loading simple excel files using UnstructuredExcelLoader()
I am trying to load a simple one sheet Excel file (.xlsx) using the langchain UnstructuredExcelLoader:
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredExcelLoader
loader = UnstructuredExcelLoader(file, mode='single', sheet_name = 'sheet1')
docs = loader.load()

However I received the following message:
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 25 were indexed

Any idea what went wrong?

is it possible to share the file?
